# How can I overlap one paragraph over two other paragraphs?

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like to have a paragraph of text (which could be long, several lines, or short, one line), centered in the window. I can accomplish this simply using flex layout, like this:

```
.center-window {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 50vh;
  padding-left: 10vw;
  padding-right: 10vw;
}
```

Underneath this paragraph I would like to have two other paragraphs; one underneath the top left corner, and one underneath the bottom right corner. The effect I am attempting to achieve is this:
[image: paragraph of text with quote marks underneath the top left and bottom right]
How can I accomplish this in a way that works both for desktop and mobile browsers?

Answer (score -1):

Well you can use ::before and ::after for positioning your elements.

this working example may help you https://nexuscode.online/editor/LU03ND1uN6

Comment: Please read [answer]. You answer should not just give hints into a direction or include links. Your answer must be self-cotnainign without relaying on external resources. Also you should include a [repro] as validation and to show how your solution would work.